# WSO2 Multi-Tenant and domains

Tags: wso2, multi-tenant, multiple-domains, wso2-api-manager

Brand new, checking out wso2 API manager 1.8.0. I work for a corp with multiple organizations/teams, so setting up multi-tenancy seems like the logical choice.

Following the quick start guide, I first created a new tenant, gave it a domain of "dev.api.myorg.company.net", added some users to it, and I can log in. I added one API.

I am able to hit the endpoint using the URL listed in the store:

http ://wso2server.company.net:8280/t/dev.api.myorg.company.net/apiname/v1/endpoint

But my expectation was that configuring this tenant with a domain would allow me to hit:

http ://dev.api.myorg.company.net:8280/apiame/v1/endpoint

I have pointed the dev domain to the wso2server IP, but when I try to access using the dev api I get:

http://pastebin.com/VNXjEv3y

Am I just missing something completely obvious? Is there extra work to make wso2 allow tenants to point their domains at it?

I have spent the last hour and a half googling and searching through tagged wso2 here, but google mostly points to the wso2 multi-tenant docs page, which is like a single page without any details.

Any pointers to better docs or suggestions for better search terms? Ive tried combinations of:

wso2 multi tenant tenancy domains hosts how to access

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for, but I was able to configure an nginx config to proxy all requests, rewriting the host to the tenant.

    server {
        listen 8280;
        server_name _;
        location ~ ^/(.*)$ {
            proxy_pass http ://wso2host:8280/t/$host/$1;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

when you create an api in a tenant it will get the following url pattern

```
http ://**<IP-where apimanger is hosted>**:8280/t/<tenantdomain>/<apiname>/<version>/
```

where 't' denotes this api url is specific to tenant and tenantdomain denotes which denant

but for super tenant url will be as following

```
http ://<IP-where apimanger is hosted>:8280/<apiname>/<version>/
```

For tenanants, domain is just a name (not having mapping to ip).So APIM will not work as you expect.Because you need to specify the IP(or domain) where APIM is hosted in the url.